# Azure search - Create Index - JSON decode error

Tags: python, json, django, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using the django framework. I'm trying to create an index in the Azure portal using the REST api [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index) they have provided. I'm getting the following error when I send my post request.

> JSONDecodeError at /createIndex

This is my method.

```
@csrf_exempt
def createIndex(request):
    endpoint = 'https://service.search.windows.net/'
    api_version = '2020-06-30'
    url = endpoint + "indexes" + api_version

    index_schema = {
        "name": "hotels-quickstar11t",  
        "fields": [
            {"name": "HotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": "true", "filterable": "true"},
            {"name": "HotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "false"},
            {"name": "Description", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "analyzer": "en.lucene"},
            {"name": "Description_fr", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "analyzer": "fr.lucene"},
            {"name": "Category", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Tags", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "ParkingIncluded", "type": "Edm.Boolean", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "LastRenovationDate", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Rating", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
            {"name": "Address", "type": "Edm.ComplexType", 
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "StreetAddress", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": "false", "sortable": "false", "facetable": "false", "searchable": "true"},
                    {"name": "City", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "StateProvince", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "PostalCode", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"},
                    {"name": "Country", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": "true", "filterable": "true", "sortable": "true", "facetable": "true"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': '******'}

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=index_schema)
    index = response.json()

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Any idea whats wrong with my method?

fyi; I have masked my api key, and service name. They are valid, as they work for other methods.

Comment: You might be interested to know that we just released a Python library for Azure Cognitive Search: https://pypi.org/project/azure-search-documents/  Your feedback is most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the following line of your code:

```
url = endpoint + "indexes" + api_version
```

If you notice, you're missing a `?` and `api-version=` query parameter (you're just including the api version value).

Please change the above line of code to

```
url = endpoint + "indexes?api-version=" + api_version
```

and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. Such a simple overlook. Thank you for the help

Comment: It happens :). At first I thought it was similar issue you posted a few days ago. Thanks to you I got to learn about `json` parameter in `requests`.